# SessionStatusCallback cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, session, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to add facebook login to my native app. I'm following this tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/native-login/

but i cannot add SessionStatusCallback() function.

I import all of these packages,

```
 import com.facebook.Request;
 import com.facebook.Response;
 import com.facebook.Session;
 import com.facebook.SessionState;
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Did you make the private class that implements `Session.StatusCallBack` like outlined in the tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you created a inner class like below, you should have inner class implementing Session.StatusCallback.

```
private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            // Respond to session state changes, ex: updating the view
    }
}
```

You can also change the name of inner class, but it must implements Session.StatusCallback